# How can I fix git commit error "Waiting for your editor to close the file..." with VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-commit

I'm trying just `git commit` and Git is giving this message:

> hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
>   /c/Users/AGT/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code: line
>   28: /Code.exe: No such file or directory error: There was a problem
>   with the editor 'code --wait'. Please supply the message using either
>   -m or -F option.

I'm using, or trying it, VS Code as default and I got this same message with it opened or closed. Commits done through VS Code or by command `git commit -m "Initial commit"` works fine.
I tried change config path with:

- `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"`
- `git config --global core.editor
  "'C:\Users\AGT\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe' -n
  -w"` and the followed variants(these with this change at error message "unexpected EOF while looking for matching"):
- C:\Users\AGT\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
- C:\Users\AGT\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code
- C:\Users\AGT\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe

No success at all.

The git status is:

```
    On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   css/app.css
        new file:   index.html
        new file:   js/app.js
```

How can I fix that to `git commit` command through Git BASH works fine with Vs Code? It's seems path issue.

Update info: I tested `git commit` with Sublime 3 and it works fine.

Comment: How did it go? Have you tried the steps in the answer below?

Comment: I'm getting a similar message while using neovim as default editor.

Comment: In fact, I had a more general problem: the neovim process would hang upon exiting while saving the file. The issue seems due to the [gutentags](https://github.com/ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags) plugin. So, if you arrived here because you are getting the `Waiting for your editor to close the file…` message when exiting neovim after editing your commit message, you could try removing gutentags.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Have you confirmed that `code` is accessible from the command line where you execute git commands?

You could run `code --version`

BTW. When I execute `where code` I get `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code` - it's no longer installed in the %App_Data% folder. **However**, this should be irrelevant if you only specify `code --wait` without the path.

In other words, here is the procedure I would attempt:

1. Confirm `code --version` works in the console you use for `git`
2. `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"`
3. Change things in you branch and then `git commit`. Does VS Code start and show COMMIT_EDITMSG file? [image]

Comment: Hi tymtam, thanks for your attention. I still got the first error message of my question. VS Code didn't start as your pic. Here what I got with what you recommended:
`code --version
/c/Users/AGT/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code: line 28: /Code.exe: No such file or directory`


`$ where code
C:\Users\AGT\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code
C:\Users\AGT\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd`

Comment: When I was looking about similar issues I've read about VS Code no longer installed in the App folders, despite of that when I tried reinstall it the default folder is App. I tried reinstall at Program Files and I got the same error, the only differences are the Path changed. 
`code --version
/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code: line 28: /Code.exe: No such file or directory`
`where code
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd`

Comment: You need to put quotation marks around your paths and you're good :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you damn right, I just tried again paying close attention at quotation marks and it works.
Weird, because I though I did the same command with quotation marks as I said in my question and it wasn't working.
`git config --global core.editor "'C:\Users\AGT\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe' -n -w"`

Comment: If you're on a Mac, and `code` is not accessible from the CLI, you need to install it in PATH: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line

Comment: I strongly suggest using VS Code editor for git commands together with GitHub Lens Extension installed. It provides a graphic interface for various command line operation that will speed up your process ie. interactive squash 

Comment: On Windows it can be necessary to call `code.cmd --wait` instead of just `code --wait`.

Answer (score 63):

`git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim` solved it for me.

Comment: got this message on Mac OS and your answer is what I was searching for, thanks :)

Comment: If you installed vim via homebrew, it'll be `/usr/local/bin/vim`. This is what worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It helped me resolve this issue

Answer (score 54):

Putting the name of the editor in double quotes produced this error for me.  Put the name of the editor in single quotes, like:

> git config --global core.editor 'vi'

Or, try switching to double quotes if you're already using single quotes.

Comment: If the editor has spaces in the path, put it in both single quotes (inner) and double quotes (outer).

Comment: Alternatively, `git config --global core.editor 'vim'`

Answer (score 5):

**For people having Atom as default editor for Git-related stuff**

When Atom was a default code editor for it, there was some kind of conflict between Atom and Visual Studio Code. Opening a Terminal in Visual Studio Code and hitting `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"` solved the problem. Then Visual Studio Code opened a new tab each time I was doing something in the console without crashing.

Answer (score 3):

Any file may be opened in any editor.
So run "ps -ax|grep vim" to check which file is opened in which editor.
And then run kill id-of-editor . For e.g. "kill 12345"
Thats all

Answer (score 2):

If your in vs code go to your source control tab on the left

then type in your comment, press ctrl & enter

if you do git status it should say nothing to commit, working tree clean..that means it worked

Comment: when `code --version` entered in the bash prompt /c/Program Files/Microsoft
 VS Code/Code.exe: Permission denied message comes, any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. For me, I had to remove quotes. This is VsCode in Windows 11 environment.

I opened my git config --global file directly

This was what I had and it did not work:

```
[merge]
  tool = vscode
[mergetool "vscode"]
  cmd = "code --wait $MERGED"
```

I changed it to this and it now works correctly:

```
[merge]
  tool = vscode
[mergetool "vscode"]
  cmd = code --wait $MERGED
```

Answer (score 1):

It is expecting you to enter the comments regarding the commit you are making enter comment and it should commit the code.

Answer (score 1):

*Maybe this might help someone*

For me, i forgot to **add vscode to path** after re-installing.

To add a file or folder to a path, follow these steps:

search for varibles =>  Enviornment variables => path => edit => paste the full path to file or folder **or** hit browse and select the path => click ok and exit.

Answer (score 1):

Strange but updating VS Code solved the issue easily for me. Hope this helps someone trying to engineer a solution without first trying the "*have you tried turning it on and off?*".

Answer (score 0):

I got that error while i configured with Atom.

I got it solved by opening the app in background before executing the command `git commit`

You can also try using `$ git commit -m "Initial commit"`
It directly passes the message without waiting for the editor to open
 NOTE: You wont be able to add description just a comment

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has to do with the path of VS Code in your case and possibly the command to set the editor `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"` not being correct.

In my case, I couldn't complete a merging command.

What really worked for me after ensuring that VS Code is correctly setup :

```
code --version
```

worked fine.
Executing
where code
showed me that the installation of code was in a different location than the local app data, which was where git was looking in. I could also tell code could not really be found because the editor was not launching when I was merging.

Finally executing

```
git config --global core.editor 'code --wait'
```

did the trick for me. Not that it's in single quotes as suggested further up in one of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

for the remote development, i needed to remove the remote VSCode binaries. although it is not ideal to remove them, VSCode remote have some issues with that. VSCode re-installs them when you re-connect (settings not affected).

```
rm -r ~/.vscode-server/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was attempting to set Notepad as the default editor. Apparently you have to add single quotes around the double quoted path, like: `git config --global core.editor '"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"'`

To be honest, I don't actually remember how many backslashes I've used to get the path right, but it currently looks like the following in the gitconfig file (located in C:\Users\user):

```
[core]
    editor = \"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe\"
```

System: Windows 10, and Powershell opened from Windows Terminal.

**EDIT:** I tested setting up VS Code as the editor with `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"` and ended up with the same problem as the OP. I then tried the full path to the program with the double and single quotes, as described earlier, and now it worked:  `git config --global core.editor '"c:\\Users\\Ian\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe"'`

Currently, the gitconfig file looks like this:

```
[core]
    editor = \"c:\\\\Users\\\\Ian\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Programs\\\\Microsoft VS Code\\\\Code.exe\"
```

so I'm not entirely sure how the escaping thing works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem during merge in VSCode.
After rebasing, I was left with commits that I needed to pull before I was able to sync, which caused a merge conflict. After resolving the conflict (to exactly the local code), there were no changes and VSCode failed to continue with the merge because there was no `%AppData%/Local/Programs/Microsoft VSCode/bin/code` file.

What resolved the issue for me was creating a file named `code` (no extension) in `%AppData%/Local/Programs/Microsoft VSCode/bin` with the commit message and then running `git merge --contine`. This created a new empty commit and completed the merge allowing me to push the changes from the rebase.

Answer (score -1):

It can be solved very easily, just copy paste below command!

git config --global core.editor "code --wait"

now run --> git commit
it is resolved!!

Comment: Please don't repeat answers