# git commit --amend hanging on hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file in vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Related post: [Git hangs with "hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file..." when closing a commit message file in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987148/git-hangs-with-hint-waiting-for-your-editor-to-close-the-file-when-closing)

I do not like the solution in the above link because it makes an entirely new `vscode` instance. I used to be able to `git commit --amend` and then a new tab in my current `vscode` instance pops up where I then edit the commit message, save, and then close, and the  `hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file` then disappears. As of this morning, this no longer happens, and I don't think I made any changes in my `~/.gitconfig`.

These are my current settings in `.gitconfig`

```
[submodule]
    recurse = true
[user]
    name = my_email
    email = my_email
[credential]
    helper = cache --timeout=31536000
[url "https://github.com/"]
  insteadOf = git://github.com/
[alias]
  tree = log --oneline --graph --all --decorate
[core]
    editor = code --wait
[diff]
  tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
  cmd = code -n --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
[merge]
  tool = vscode
[mergetool "vscode"]
  cmd = code --wait $MERGED
```

Does anyone know of a solution for this?

P.S. I just tried the solution in the linked post where the amend is routed to a different instance, and that didn't work either. When i closed the new instance, it's still hanging on `hint: Waiting for....`

Answer (score 0):

I don't like that this bug is not fixed.
My solution: I go to my VM and commit via Git GUI, for example.
It clears it on Mac side (that's where my project runs) without re-opening or new instances.