# Git rebase stuck on Waiting for your editor to close the file

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, rebase, git-interactive-rebase

I'm using VS Code. I just executed

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

which opened up the configuration window (for selecting which commits you want to work with) in a new VS Code instance. I changed one commit to the `edit` option, saved it, and closed that editor instance, but my terminal is still saying

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
```

I tried restarting VS Code and went through this process again, and it's still doing the same thing. I didn't have issues yesterday with interactive rebasing, so I'm not sure what's happening.

Could someone advise?

Edit:
After making this post,
I just tried again and after running `git rebase --abort`, I now  seem to be having a separate issue after executing `git rebase -i origin/master`:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... Unable to connect to VS Code server.
Error in request
error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait --new-window'.
```

Comment: So I just edited `.gitconfig` and changed `  editor = code --wait --new-window` to `  editor = code --wait`, and this made it opens up in a tab instead of another VS Code instance. Saving and closing the tab seems to work and no longer hangs, but I'd still like to know what was going on with the previous issue, which as I stated in the OP, had not been an issue until today

Comment: It's an issue with your git file editor configuration. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52195877/how-can-i-fix-git-commit-error-waiting-for-your-editor-to-close-the-file-wi

Comment: @Drakinite I think that post is related to an incorrect specification of the path of the editor. In my case, my editor is available

Comment: I was having the exact same problem and the solution to that question fixed it for me. Have you tried it?